# Dictation options for RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, speech-recognition, dictation, naturallyspeaking

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking for dictating emails and documents to minimize keyboard and mouse use, but have not yet found a useful way of using dictation for RStudio other than creating macros for certain common actions e.g. "comment that" or "set working directory". I am looking for a way to do at least some of the coding itself by voice, acknowledging that some keystrokes may still be needed but any minimization would be helpful.

Searching other forums I have come across VoiceCode, which may be a solution but is only available for Mac so far and I am on Windows for various reasons. I have also seen Vocola which appears to be a scripting language for writing macros but not sure this would help.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Bryan

Comment: Somewhat related: https://github.com/yihui/shiny-apps/tree/master/voice

Comment: Lots and lots of discussions and examples of using Dragon to code by voice over at http://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/index.cfm  Somewhere you can find the links to some YouTube videos showing people doing this extremely well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any voice coding solution specifically designed for R Studio.

The thread [How can one use Dragon NaturallySpeaking to code more efficiently?](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/q/3605/2476) contains several pointers.

In short, there are many initiatives but everything is fragmented.