# Is there a program that allows you to dictate R code hands-free?

Tags: r, dictation

Microsoft speech dictation has come a long way, but you’d have to spell out every letter if you wanted to write code for R and RStudio. Does anyone have any better solutions than that for someone who needs to be hands free?

There are two older posts on this subject in this community, but all the answers are to links that no longer work. So I was hoping someone would have up to date information. Thanks!

Comment: Previous discussion for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580293/dictation-options-for-rstudio

Comment: And the dead link from the previous discussion on the Internet Archive - https://web.archive.org/web/20160711182748/http://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/3605/how-can-one-use-dragon-naturallyspeaking-to-code-more-efficiently